# DAX TOTALQTD does not show GrandTotal properly

Tags: aggregation, dax

Using the DAX function to build out the Quarter to Date calculations:

`Measure 1 QTD:=TOTALQTD([Measure 1],DATESYTD(DimDate[Date],"09-31"),ALL(DimDate))`

it functions properly aside from the Grand Total:

[image]

What I need is for the `GrandTotal` not to be the last quarter to date sum, but the total year end. In this case it would be ~$915,000.

How can DAX to configured to permit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking it to perform a different computation for the Grand Total. To do this you need to have some sort of condition to let it know when you want to compute the Grand Total and when you want to compute everything else.

One possibility is to use the `HASONEVALUE` function like this:

```
IF(HASONEVALUE(DimDate[Date],
    TOTALQTD([Measure 1], DATESYTD(DimDate[Date], "09-30"), ALL(DimDate)),
    TOTALYTD([Measure 1], DimDate[Date], ALL(DimDate), "09-30"))
```

This should give you QTD when you have a single date filter context and YTD for the Grand Total since it has multiple dates values in the filter context.

Comment: This was a perfect solution. I do have one other question, want to start a chat?

Comment: @Sauron Not sure how chat works on here. Post your question and I'll answer it if I can.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118392/need-to-default-to-last-nonblank-value

Comment: Would you like to setup a chat? I am free