# Need to default to last nonblank value

Tags: aggregation, dax

At present that dax calculation is a simple SUM, but I need to default to the last non-blank value for the GrandTotal:

For example, instead of stating 167, it should not 9:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other question you asked, you can use `HASONEVALUE` to change the behavior of the Grand Total. If the column you are summing is named `Table1[Value]` then the measure you want will look something like this:

```
LastNonBlankValue = 
    VAR LastNonBlankDate = CALCULATE(MAX(DimDate[Date]), Table1[Value] > 0)
    RETURN IF(HASONEVALUE(DimDate[Date],
               SUM(Table1[Value]),
               CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Value]),
                         ALLSELCTED(DimDate[Date]),
                         DimDate[Date] = LastNonBlankDate))
```

This is intended to find the last non-blank date, and sum over just that date for the Grand Total.

Since I don't know your table and column names or context, you'll need to modify this to suit your particular situation, but it should give you an idea of what to try.